# How to show navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am stuck at a point where I have got my UITableViewController showing
It has has  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem added in the code but. that is not visible when I run the app

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    }

    @objc
    func handleLogout() {
        let loginController = LoginController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is how my Main.storyboard looks like

[image]

Update after adding Navigation controller

[image]

Comment: Hey Dhara I tried that but still the same, I added the screenshot of my story board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add navigationController to your viewcontroller then it will work, for that select your viewcontroller -> go to Editor-> Embed in -> Navgation Controller

Comment: I tried that but did not work, I added the screen shot to my question after adding Navigation controller

Comment: I think you have not assigned class to your TableViewController. Please check

Comment: sorry what exactly do you mean by that, I have not. changed my code of ViewController it is same as you see in my question

Comment: I mean select your TableViewController and check have you assigned a class in which you have written leftbarbutton code.In your case its ViewController class

Comment: Perfect mate, that was it.. thank you so muchhhh you are a STAR

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a navigationController to the view controller and give entry point to the navigation controller. [

[image]

Then add navigationItem to viewcontroller and then add barbutton to navigation item.

Comment: So I should have a viewcontroller, Navigation controller and a Table view controller. and Navigation controller will be main view?

Comment: Instead of view controller just add your Table view controller.

Comment: Table view controller is on the right of navigation controller as you have in your picture. so you mean I need another table view controller on the left of the navigation too?

Comment: Nope. What you have shown in your secon image is correct. What I mean is to ada a navigation Item to your table view controller and a bar button item inside the navigation item at left side of navigation item as in the image me given